# Discord embed join messages

Tags: typescript, bots, embed, discord

I keep coming across a error while trying to embed join messages

I've tried re writing the code in other ways but still nothing

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

 let guild = member.guild; 
 let memberTag = member.user.tag; 
 if(guild.systemChannel){
 guild.systemChannel.send(new Discord.RichEmbed() 
 .setTitle("A new user joined") 
 .setDescription(memberTag + " has joined the guild") 
 .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL)
 .addField("Members now", member.guild.memberCount) 
 .setTimestamp()
 );
}
```

`guild.systemChannel.send` is the error I am having "send"

> error: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this script in `index`:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

    let welcomeMsg = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome") as Discord.TextChannel;

    let welcomeEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("A new user joined") 
        .setDescription(`${member.displayName} has joined the guild`) 
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL)
        .addField("Members now", member.guild.memberCount);

    await welcomeMsg.send(welcomeEmbed)
        .catch(error.console);
```